# Parse javascript array elements from html page using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, dom

I'm a newbie php dev and I'm looking for a solution to this case:

I want to parse specific elements from and JavaScript array located on html page using php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var elements = [{"id":"xxxx","file":"somewhere/\something.mp4","somethingelse":"else","anotherelse":"else2"}....]
```

I need to parse exactly "somewhere/\something.mp4" without "\" into my array to become a correct url list.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You do have a valid object here..Why do you need to parse it ?

Comment: `located on html page using php`?

Comment: I have an html page with js tag inserted into it, it has urls in format showed above, i need those urls, in addition i need them without "\"

Comment: If you wrote the JavaScript, then you have access to this information already, otherwise I would use something like PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: Try this: `alert(elements[0].file)` you will not see any `\\`. It is there just to escape..

Comment: How to extract a JSON object that was defined in a HTML page javascript block? Found solution for Python, but i need it in php urgently..